# Como cadastrar novas coisas no Wordpress sem a utilização de post type?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, custom-post-types

Galera estou estudando a criação de temas em Wordpress e achei a utilização do post types muito interessante... Só que tem certas situações que fica inviável e fica com uma cara de gambiarra...

Tem alguma outra maneira de fazer o cadastro de novas tabelas no mysql sem utilizar as tabelas principais do Wordpress?

Edit:
Estou tentando fazer um cadastro de uma galeria de imagens e de emails.... Mas sem utilizar a tabela wp_posts... O ideal seria eu ter uma tabela wp_gallery e outra wp_emails

Comment: Sim, mas depende do modo que você quer, quer cadastrar oque? valores para post, categorias? Oque?

Comment: Eu queria fazer um cadastro de uma galeria de imagens e de emails.... Mas sem utilizar a tabela wp_posts... O ideal seria eu ter uma tabela wp_gallery e outra wp_emails

Answer (score 0):

Geralmente este tipo de cadastro é feito em páginas ou posts, usando como exemplo a galeria de imagens que você citou, se ela aparecerá na página inicial do site, você pode criar ela no editor de conteúdo da página, usando campos customizados, shortcodes ou plugins. Mas se for uma coisa muito específica você consegue sim criar tabelas no banco, consultar etc. utilizando o [wpdb](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb)